# How to convert ArrayList pulled through Dart Flutter Firestore to ListTile?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application like this:

[image]

Also codes:

```
String yapilacaklar;
```

---

```
            Container(
              height: 500,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(yapilacaklar.toString() ?? "Yok")
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

ArrayList from Firestore is kept in `yapilacaklar` variable.

`yapilacaklar` = `["Görev 1", "Görev 2"]`

I want to show these items one by one in `ListTile`. How can I do that? Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[image]

Comment: Have your tried using `ListView.builder()` ?

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar I edited the topic. I tried `ListView.builder` but I couldn't manage to list the items in ArrayList one by one.

Comment: Its an array so you need to give index to your `yapilacaklar` but you are just printing the whole array. Try doing `yapilacaklar[index].toString()` like this.

Comment: Hi @EmirBolat did the last comment helped you to find the answer?